# EDITHibernate XML mapping - Nullable Integer

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have a problem with an Hibernate mapping, I know there are millions of posts on the subject, and I read quite a lot of them but I still can't work it out.

I have a NULL value for a field mapped on an Integer and when I execute the select, I get this error:

```
Mar 3, 2016 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:583)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3848)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:982)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.dao.BillingItemDAO.fetch(BillingItemDAO.java:42)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.model.BillingItemModel.updateDataFromDatabase(BillingItemModel.java:191)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.model.BillingItemModel.fetchData(BillingItemModel.java:121)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.model.BillingItemModelFactory.getBillingItemModel(BillingItemModelFactory.java:212)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.BillingMgr.setBillingItemModel(BillingMgr.java:1339)
    at com.squire.svi.billing.BillingMgr.doBillingTableLink(BillingMgr.java:1324)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:127)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Here is the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14-Feb-2011 16:39:32 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.5.Beta -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.squire.svi.billing.Routing" table="Routing" lazy="false">

        [...]

        <property name="timeOfDayGroupId" type="java.lang.Integer" not-null="false" length="5">
            <column name="TODGroupId" default="0" />
        </property>

        [...]

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The table is as follow, the mapped column is the last one:

```
mysql> describe Routing;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Prefix          | varchar(30)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Route           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Cost            | decimal(13,4)    | YES  | MUL | 0.0000  |                |
| Priority        | int(10)          | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| Loadshare       | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| LoadBalance     | tinyint(1)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| OnNet           | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| country_code    | varchar(40)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| routing_info    | varchar(40)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Outgoing_Format | varchar(40)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RoutePlanId     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EnableTBR       | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| TODGroupId      | int(5)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> select * from Routing;
+----+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Id | Prefix | Route | Cost   | Priority | Loadshare | LoadBalance | OnNet | country_code | routing_info | Outgoing_Format | RoutePlanId | EnableTBR | TODGroupId |
+----+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
|  2 | ewqe   |     2 | 0.0000 |        0 |         0 |           0 |  NULL | NULL         | NULL         | NULL            |        NULL |         1 |       NULL |
|  7 | 0%     |     2 | 0.0000 |        2 |         0 |           0 |  NULL | NULL         | NULL         | NULL            |        NULL |         0 |          0 |
+----+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The setter on my bean is as follow:

```
private Integer timeOfDayGroupId;

public void setTimeOfDayGroupId(Integer timeOfDayGroupId) {
    LoggingManager.logGeneral("setTimeOfDayGroupId "+timeOfDayGroupId);
    if(null != timeOfDayGroupId){
        this.timeOfDayGroupId = timeOfDayGroupId;

    }else{
        this.timeOfDayGroupId = 0;
    }

    LoggingManager.logGeneral("timeOfDayGroupId "+this.timeOfDayGroupId);
}
```

I also tried with an int as parameter.
But the logging at the first line is never called, I get the exception first

If I set the TODGroupId value to 0, then it works fine. So This NULL is the problem.

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks

EDIT: The entity class

```
package com.squire.svi.billing;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import com.squire.svi.cache.Cacheable;
import com.squire.svi.logging.LoggingManager;
import com.squire.svi.util.StringSortable;

public class Routing extends SelectItem implements Serializable, BillingItem,
    Cacheable<String>, StringSortable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** identifier field */
    private Integer id;

    /** persistent field */
    private String prefix; // also used as the name for this object

    /** persistent field, this is shown as the route on the display */
    private com.squire.svi.billing.Customer customer;

    private Double cost;
    private Integer priority;
    private Integer percentage;
    private Double quality;
    private String routeBy;
    private Boolean loadshare;
    private Boolean onNet;
    private boolean enableTBR;
    private Integer timeOfDayGroupId;
    private com.squire.svi.billing.Routeplan routeplan;

    public Boolean getLoadshare() {
        return loadshare;
    }

    public Boolean isLoadshare() {
        return loadshare;
    }

    public void setLoadshare(Boolean loadshare) {
        this.loadshare = loadshare;
    }

    public boolean getEnableTBR() {
        return isEnableTBR();
    }

    public boolean isEnableTBR() {
        return enableTBR;
    }

    public void setEnableTBR(boolean enableTBR) {
        this.enableTBR = enableTBR;
    }

    public int getTimeOfDayGroupId() {
        LoggingManager.logGeneral("getTimeOfDayGroupId "+timeOfDayGroupId);
        return timeOfDayGroupId;
    }

    public void setTimeOfDayGroupId(Integer timeOfDayGroupId) {
        LoggingManager.logGeneral("setTimeOfDayGroupId integer "+timeOfDayGroupId);
        if(null != timeOfDayGroupId){
            this.timeOfDayGroupId = timeOfDayGroupId;

        }else{
            this.timeOfDayGroupId = 0;
        }

        LoggingManager.logGeneral("timeOfDayGroupId "+this.timeOfDayGroupId);
    }   

[...]

}
```

EDIT: After removing the default value from the mapping, I still have the same error.

```
<property name="timeOfDayGroupId" type="java.lang.Integer" not-null="false" length="5">
    <column name="TODGroupId" />
</property>
```

Edit again: Writing the mapping this way works

```
<property name="timeOfDayGroupId" type="integer">
  <column name="TODGroupId" not-null="false" default="null" />
</property>
```

Thanks newohybat.

Comment: Can you show the entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown while deserializing the entity from database and invoking setters of your entity.

I suspect that Hibernate doesn't expect NULL value in the database, because it relies on the fact, that the default value was inserted on INSERT. This has to be assured in database.

So my advice is to get the table into expected state (default value instead of NULL) before querying from Hibernate.

Comment: Yes that was my first idea, but the problem is that an other application requires that this value can be null.

Comment: Then alter you hibernate mappings to reflect that.

Comment: In which way? I alrady use an Integer, and I say it is nullable, I don't see what more I can do in the mapping.

Comment: Remove the 'default' definition on your column if there's no such thing in the target table.